# Object relational mapping ('and_' not working)

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

and_  is not working

can anyone help me out. i am new to flask

test.py

```
from flask import session,Flask,render_template,request
from models import *
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    query= book.query.filter(and_ (book.title=='we all lost',book.publication_year==2050)).all()
    for i in query:
        print(i.title)
    return render_template('hellotesting.html',m=query)
```

hellotesting.html

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <ol>
            <li>{{m.title}} </li>
            <li>{{m.author}} </li>
            <li>{{m.publication_year}}</li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

error
NameError
NameError: name 'and_' is not defined

---

i dont know why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to import it before you can use it

```
from sqlalchemy import and_
```

and then

```
query = book.query.filter(and_(book.title=='we all lost',book.publication_year==2050)).all()
```

Also in your hellotesting.html file you try to display attribute of queryset (something like list of your model instances), not particular object and it will raise exception. You have to get any object from queryset in function or in template before call it's attribute.

In function you can do something like

```
query = book.query.filter(and_(book.title=='we all lost',book.publication_year==2050)).first()
```

or

```
book = query[0]
```

and then put that object to render_template function or you can do something similar in template like

```
{{ m[0].title }}
```

Read documentation for more examples and explenations